# REE (Ruby Enterprise Edition) on El Capitan, installed through RVM, giving: [BUG] Segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, osx-elcapitan, ruby-enterprise-edition

I had 10.10 installed on my MacBook Pro Retina. During this time, I had REE 1.8.7-2011.12 on my machine working fine. I upgraded to 10.11 El Capitan and everything worked fine. I recently uninstalled and reinstalled RVM to clean up my Ruby Environment. It's been working great with Ruby 2.2.3, and other various versions. However, one of the projects I work on is a legacy application that requires the specific version of REE, `ree-1.8.7-2011.12`.

It acts as if it's installed properly. However, when I went to install my first gem, `gem install bundler`, I get:

`/Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.12/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:60: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-12-28 MBARI 8/0x6770 on patchlevel 357) [i686-darwin15.0.0], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2011.12`

I've spent a good portion of my day trying to resolve this without having to just create a virtual machine for this, though it would probably solve my problems. Any advice on how to prevent the Segmentation fault?

Comment: Do you have to stick to REE? It's pretty much outdated and is not supported anymore.

Comment: I do, we're in the process of rebuilding the application in a 2.2.3 environment. Until then, I'm attached to that for working on the legacy project.